# Excel Web Add-In Read Custom XML Property

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

The workbooks that my add-in is going to manage already have a Custom XML. From what I understood, in order to use **customXmlPartCollectionObject.getByNamespace()** method, the XML must follow a 
[defined name declaration](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/customxmlpartcollection.md#getbynamespacenamespaceuri-string) (?).
If that's right I cannot change the Custom property because another Add-in will use it. From the Custom XML bellow I need to get all the tags **rows** and **columns** values.
Could someone give me an example on how to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><carbono_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>0</id><type>ItemFiledInfoField</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>4</row><column>4</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>4</row><column>5</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><data_type>FieldTypeText</data_type><type_definition_name>Request</type_definition_name><type_attribute_name>Date</type_attribute_name><ckb_reading>False</ckb_reading><range_was_merged>True</range_was_merged></type_data></object_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>1</id><type>ItemFiledInfoField</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>5</row><column>4</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>5</row><column>5</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><data_type>FieldTypeText</data_type><type_definition_name>Request</type_definition_name><type_attribute_name>Resp</type_attribute_name><ckb_reading>False</ckb_reading><range_was_merged>True</range_was_merged></type_data></object_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>2</id><type>ItemFiledInfoField</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>4</row><column>8</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>4</row><column>9</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><data_type>FieldTypeText</data_type><type_definition_name>Request</type_definition_name><type_attribute_name>Crit1</type_attribute_name><ckb_reading>False</ckb_reading><range_was_merged>True</range_was_merged></type_data></object_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>3</id><type>ItemFiledInfoField</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>5</row><column>8</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>5</row><column>9</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><data_type>FieldTypeText</data_type><type_definition_name>Request</type_definition_name><type_attribute_name>Crit2</type_attribute_name><ckb_reading>False</ckb_reading><range_was_merged>True</range_was_merged></type_data></object_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>4</id><type>ItemFiledInfoField</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>4</row><column>12</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>4</row><column>13</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><data_type>FieldTypeText</data_type><type_definition_name>Request</type_definition_name><type_attribute_name>Crit3</type_attribute_name><ckb_reading>False</ckb_reading><range_was_merged>True</range_was_merged></type_data></object_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>5</id><type>ItemFiledInfoField</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>5</row><column>12</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>5</row><column>13</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><data_type>FieldTypeText</data_type><type_definition_name>Request</type_definition_name><type_attribute_name>Crit4</type_attribute_name><ckb_reading>False</ckb_reading><range_was_merged>True</range_was_merged></type_data></object_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>6</id><type>ItemFiledInfoTable</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>7</row><column>2</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>27</row><column>15</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><type_definition_name>Request</type_definition_name><type_attributes><type_attribute><type_table>Crit5</type_table><label_table>Critério 5</label_table><column_index>0</column_index><type_attribute_column>Text</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col01</type_table><label_table>Jan</label_table><column_index>1</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col02</type_table><label_table>Fev</label_table><column_index>2</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col03</type_table><label_table>Mar</label_table><column_index>3</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col04</type_table><label_table>Abr</label_table><column_index>4</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col05</type_table><label_table>Mai</label_table><column_index>5</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col06</type_table><label_table>Jun</label_table><column_index>6</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col07</type_table><label_table>Jul</label_table><column_index>7</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col08</type_table><label_table>Ago</label_table><column_index>8</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col09</type_table><label_table>Set</label_table><column_index>9</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col10</type_table><label_table>Out</label_table><column_index>10</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col11</type_table><label_table>Nov</label_table><column_index>11</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Col12</type_table><label_table>Dez</label_table><column_index>12</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>False</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>ColTot</type_table><label_table>TOTAL</label_table><column_index>13</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute></type_attributes></type_data></object_data><object_data><real_id>0</real_id><id>7</id><type>ItemFiledInfoTable</type><value/><shapeID>0</shapeID><range><top_left_cell><row>28</row><column>2</column></top_left_cell><bottom_right_cell><row>29</row><column>15</column></bottom_right_cell></range><type_data><type_definition_name>RequestTot</type_definition_name><type_attributes><type_attribute><type_table>Total</type_table><label_table>TOTAL</label_table><column_index>0</column_index><type_attribute_column>Text</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot01</type_table><label_table>Jan</label_table><column_index>1</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot02</type_table><label_table>Fev</label_table><column_index>2</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot03</type_table><label_table>Mar</label_table><column_index>3</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot04</type_table><label_table>Abr</label_table><column_index>4</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot05</type_table><label_table>Mai</label_table><column_index>5</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot06</type_table><label_table>Jun</label_table><column_index>6</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot07</type_table><label_table>Jul</label_table><column_index>7</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot08</type_table><label_table>Ago</label_table><column_index>8</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot09</type_table><label_table>Set</label_table><column_index>9</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot10</type_table><label_table>Out</label_table><column_index>10</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot11</type_table><label_table>Nov</label_table><column_index>11</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>Tot12</type_table><label_table>Dez</label_table><column_index>12</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute><type_attribute><type_table>TotTot</type_table><label_table>TOTAL</label_table><column_index>13</column_index><type_attribute_column>Numeric</type_attribute_column><column_read_only>True</column_read_only></type_attribute></type_attributes></type_data></object_data></carbono_data>
```

Comment: How are the XML Parts being created? Is another add-in creating them? How is the other add-in reading them, since it can't use the getByNamespace method either?

Comment: Yes, it's another add-in who creates the XML. Well the other add-in won't help, because it is a VSTO, It uses C# XML libraries to read and write.

Comment: You could try using an empty string for the parameter, but I don't think  that will work. If not, then I don't think there's anyway that you can use the getByNamespace method.